# error I can not see my webpage

Tags: error

[24-May-2017 18:10:44 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/migps/public_html/gpsenmexico/system/database/mysql.php on line 67

Comment: This is a question for stackoverflow.com but I'll give a quick answer. The only things that can be closed are things that are open of the same type which in your case is an active mysql connection.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, mysql_ is deprecated now.  You should be using PDO or at the least mysqli_

Be that as it may, you are missing the connection  e.g. `mysql_close($conn)`